# Tweepy.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found 50 - User not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to make a twitter bot in python using tweepy, when running the below code I get error:

> tweepy.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found
>
> 50 - User not found.

My code:

```py
import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

class FavRetweetListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        self.me = api.get_user()

    def on_status(self, tweet):
        logger.info(f"Processing tweet id {tweet.id}")
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
            tweet.user.id == self.me.id:
            # This tweet is a reply or I'm its author so, ignore it
            return
        if not tweet.favorited:
            # Mark it as Liked, since we have not done it yet
            try:
                tweet.favorite()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav", exc_info=True)
        if not tweet.retweeted:
            # Retweet, since we have not retweeted it yet
            try:
                tweet.retweet()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav and retweet", exc_info=True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        logger.error(status)

def main(keywords):
    api = create_api()
    tweets_listener = FavRetweetListener(api)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
    stream.filter(track=keywords, languages=["en"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(["Python", "Tweepy"])
```

Is this something with the `` `tweet.user.id == self.me.id:` `` ?

Comment: I'm not sure - you could try checking the value of `self.me.id` - is it an actual valid user ID? Where are you setting the access token and access token and secret, and do they correspond to a valid user?

Answer (score 0):

The user does not exist anymore in Twitter.

You must catch the error with an except statement in python.

You did not provide the exact line where the error happen but you should try to catch it with something like this:

```py
try:
    api.get_user()
except tweepy.errors.NotFound:
    print("user not found")
```